# Sorting String/Number Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to arrange the array by the value of the number in the array mystr Example - "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"  -->  "Thi1s is2 3a T4est".  I have the function working except it is duplicating the answers and I can't figure out why. This is my result: ["Thi1s", "Thi1s", "is2", "is2", "3a", "3a", "T4est", "T4est"]

```js
let newArr = [];
let myStr = "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a";
let lastArr = [];
let sortedArr = [];

function order(words) {
  //Convert String to Array
  newArr = words.split(" ");
  newArr.forEach((word, index) => {
    //  Find words that contain numbers
    let wordvalue = word.match(/\d+/g);

    // Convert string back to number
    wordvalue = parseInt(wordvalue);
    lastArr.push({ wrd: word, wrdv: wordvalue });

    // Sorts
    lastArr.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.wrdv - b.wrdv;
    });
  });

  sortedArr = lastArr.map((item) => item.wrd);
  return sortedArr;
}

order(myStr);
```

Comment: your code works fine. you need only add the output: `console.log(order(myStr));`

Comment: So... I realized why I was getting duplicates. I have i order(myStr) coded in then in console I did order(myStr); When I removed the hard coded function i did not get the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

How are you outputting the results?  When I send it to an alert I am not seeing any duplicates.

```js
let newArr = [];
let myStr = "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a";
let lastArr = [];
let sortedArr = [];

function order(words) {
  //Convert String to Array
  newArr = words.split(" ");
  newArr.forEach((word, index) => {
    //  Find words that contain numbers
    let wordvalue = word.match(/\d+/g);

    // Convert string back to number
    wordvalue = parseInt(wordvalue);
    lastArr.push({ wrd: word, wrdv: wordvalue });

    // Sorts
    lastArr.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.wrdv - b.wrdv;
    });
  });

  sortedArr = lastArr.map((item) => item.wrd);
  return sortedArr;
}

order(myStr);

alert(sortedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank yall for your help! So... I realized why I was getting duplicates. I have i order(myStr) coded in then in console I did order(myStr); When I removed the hard coded function i did not get the duplicate